# What does "lockpicking chance" mean?

Tags: you-must-build-a-boat

I just recruited a monster who gave me +3% lockpick chance. What does this mean? Do I have a chance to simply open chests as I walk up to them without needing to match key tiles? Or do I have to do something special to use it?

Answer (score 2):

It's a "critical hit chance" for opening chests. There's a small chance that a single set of 3 Key blocks can "lockpick" and open more than 1 lock on a chest (or the entire chest, I haven't really tested it). A successful lockpick will produce a "lockpick" message